# Cannot boot LiveCD/USB sessions on a particular machine ("Kernel Bug" error)

Tags: 11.10, xubuntu, live-cd, installation, boot-failure

I cant install ubuntu 11.10 nor Xubuntu 11.10 on my computer, I tried using bootable USB's and CD's, but always after the ubuntu bootscreen, the installer shows a console with many lines like:

> 5.056005 CR2 0000000000002
>
> Kernel Bug

My bootables usb's and cd's works perfectly on other computers.
My computer specs are:

```
Motherboard: Intel D865PERL
Processor: Intel Pentium 4 HT 3.0Ghz (Hyperthreading enabled)
RAM: 1.5GB (2x512Mb + 2x256Mb)
Harddrive: SAMSUNG 160GB Sata II
           Seagate 120GB Sata I
Graphics Card: Ati Radeon 9250 AGP 128Mb
```

I know my computer is a bit old, but Ubuntu 10.04 works perfectly, I also tried removing some RAM modules and removing my harddrives but Ubuntu 11.10 (nor Xubuntu 11.10) cant boot even in live cd.

I dont want to install ubuntu 10 and update it to ubuntu 11.10, what can I do to install ubuntu 11.10 or xubuntu 11.10 on my computer?

Comment: Solved! I used F6 and selected acpi=off, I dont know why it works, but works!!

Answer (score 1):

Solved by the OP

> I used F6 and selected acpi=off, I dont know why it works, but works!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable hyperthreading via the BIOS options, and then you will be able to boot in Ubuntu 11.10.  The issue is somewhat documented in [this bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/874436).

However, since it is a kernel bug in Linux 3.0, I have not been able to find a way to report it against the kernel.

The only downside to turning off Hyperthreading is that your PC will run just a bit slower.